# Uncaught TypeError: allClearButton.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

since I am new in programming I was doing a project with the help of the tutorial. I get this error: **Uncaught TypeError: allClearButton.addEventListener is not a function**.
The code is identical to the tutor's code. Maybe you, guys, could help me? I sincerely don't understand why it occurs, since the code is identical as I have mentioned.

**JS**

```
class Calculator {
    constructor(previousOperandTextElement,currentOperandTextElement) {
        this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement
        this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
        this.readyToReset = false;
        this.clear()
    }
    clear() {
        this.currentOperand = "";
        this.previousOperand = "";
        this.operation = undefined;
    }

    delete() {
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString().slice(0, -1);
    }

    appendNumber(number) {
        if (number=== "." && this.currentOperand.includes(".")) return
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString();
    }

    chooseOperation(operation) {
        if (this.currentOperand === "") return
        if (this.previousOperand !== "" && this.previous.Operand !== "") this.compute();
        this.operation = operation;
        this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand;
        this.currentOperand= "";

    }

    compute() {
      let computation
      const prev = parseFloat(this.previousOperand);
      const current = parseFloat(this.currentOperand);
      if (isNaN(prev) || isNaN(current)) return;
      switch (this.operation) {
        case '+':
          computation = prev + current
          break;
        case '-':
          computation = prev - current
          break;
        case '*':
          computation = prev * current
          break;
        case '/':
          computation = prev / current
          break;
        default:
          return;
      }
this.readyToReset = true;
this.currentOperand = computation;
this.operation = undefined;
this.previousOperand = '';
    }

    updateDisplay() {
        this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand;
           if (this.operation !== null) {
             this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = 
               `${this.previousOperand} ${this.operation}` 
           } else {
        this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = "";
           }
    }
}





const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-number]");
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-operation]");
const equalsButton = document.querySelectorAll("[data-equals]");
const deleteButton = document.querySelectorAll("[data-delete]");
const allClearButton = document.querySelectorAll("[data-all-clear]");
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelectorAll("[data-previous-operand]");
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelectorAll("[data-current-operand]");

const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement,currentOperandTextElement);

allClearButton.addEventListener('click', () => { /*THE PROBLEM IS HERE, BUT I DONT UNDERSTAND IT */
  calculator.clear();
  calculator.updateDisplay();
})

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click' , () => {
      if(calculator.previousOperand === "" &&
      calculator.currentOperand !== "" &&
      calculator.readyToReset) {
        calculator.currentOperand = "";
        calculator.readyToReset = false;
      }
      calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
      calculator.updateDisplay();
    })
})

operationButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click' , () => {
        calculator.chooseOperation(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay();
    })
})

equalsButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
  calculator.compute();
  calculator.updateDisplay();
})

deleteButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
  calculator.delete();
  calculator.updateDisplay();
})
```

Comment: `.querySelectorAll()` returns a collection of HTML nodes/elements, you can't add a listener to a collection, you need to loop through each element of `allClearButton` collection and add the listener individually

Comment: Try to wrap your code inside `document.onLoad` event.